# 1 is coming in the output of ("aba" < "a") ? 1:0 in c or c++ program. Why?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
  if("abc" < "a")
     cout << 1 << "\n";
  else 
      cout << 0 << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output: 1

Why 1 is coming in the output?

Comment: `"aba" < "a"` compares the **addresses** of the two string literals. If you must use C-style strings, use `std::strcmp` to test for equality. Or use `std::string("aba") < "a"`.